# Configure next.js image path

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When rendering a next.js image with image optimization enabled, eg:

```
import Image from 'next/image';

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Image
      src="https://example.com/my-image.jpg"
      width={500}
      height={300}
    />
  );
}
```

The final url of the image will look something like:

```
/_next/image/?url=https://example.com/my-image.jpg
```

Is it possible to change the url prefix from `/_next/image/` to `/_next/foo/bar/`?